# how to use a vector to call colums from a data frame

Tags: r

I have a vector called gas

```
gas <- c("Hydrogen","Methane")
```

I also have a data frame called df that looks like

```
df <-   ID  Hydrogen  Methane
         1     2        20
         1     3        19
         1     2        23
         2     8        13
```

ect..

Normally to use a variable in a data frame I would use df$Hydrogen for example but what I want to know is can I also call Hydrogen by using the vector above? e.g.

```
data$gas[1] 
#In other words I would like the following to be true:
data$gas[1] == data$Hydrogen
```

what syntax, if any, would I use to obtain this?

Thanks

Comment: Something like `df[gas]`?

Comment: You may not ever use `$` with variable names. It's only used when you know the exact name of a column. In all other cases, use `[ ]` indexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a specific gas, try:

```
df[,gas[1]]
```

For all gases:

```
df[gas]
```

Comment: The first one works the best.  The df[gas] doesn't work for plotting